# SQLServer Error: 10054, Communication link failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

> [382] Logon to server 'servername' failed (ConnLogJobHistory)
>
> [165] ODBC Error: 0, A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [SQLSTATE 08001]
>
> [298] SQLServer Error: 10054, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]

All of a sudden SQL Server 2012 Agent has returned this error in the Agentlog for the past 3 days. During this error no job or no heavy load queries were running on SQL Server. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: What time does it happen?  What is this agent job doing when the error happens?  Can you connect to the server manually when the error occurs?

Comment: Check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b43775b9-cd96-4f14-bd1e-b40172c5fc83/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: This happens mostly in mornings, and by the time it threw error no job were running. I haven't tried connecting to the server while it was occurring since we happen to see the error later.